# What is the tag "ifs" for?

Tags: support

There is a tag "ifs" out there, and there is no information for it. I was hoping it would refer to questions related to the ERP system IFS, but only one question seemed to suggest this interpretation. What can be done to add wiki and clean up this confusion?

Answer (score 6):

I think it was supposed to be created for Integrated File System for Java or Internal Field Separator for Bash questions.

I would imagine it has been hijacked on occasion for questions regarding "if, then and else" etc.

It should probably be deleted as it is too vague and has multiple meanings.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 8 questions with this tag, and they really have little connection to each other:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifs

They should be removed.