# The [ifs] tag is used for 2 separate things

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I think [ifs](/questions/tagged/ifs) might correspond to IBM's [Integrated File System](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fifs%2Frzaaxkickoff.htm) according to this [2-year-old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76339/what-is-the-tag-ifs-for).

But currently out of the 27 question tagged with [ifs](/questions/tagged/ifs), most of it have to do with the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s "Internal Field Separator".

What should be done here?

- create a new tag for "Internal Field Separator" e.g. [bash-ifs](/questions/tagged/bash-ifs), and keep the IBM's under [ifs](/questions/tagged/ifs)?
- create a new tag for "Integrated File System" e.g. [ibm-ifs](/questions/tagged/ibm-ifs), and keep the other one under [ifs](/questions/tagged/ifs)?
- just remove the [ifs](/questions/tagged/ifs) tag from the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) questions?

Comment: @DannyBeckett, you're absolutely right. I shouldn't have read into the tag's name literally. Noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Unix shell [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) (17)

- [BASH: How do you "split" the date command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288662/bash-how-do-you-split-the-date-command)
- [String tokenisation algorithm won't tokenise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881052/string-tokenisation-algorithm-wont-tokenise)
- [IFS variable issue in script with Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217660/ifs-variable-issue-in-script)
- [IFS more than a character usage with R script and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203600/ifs-more-than-a-character-usage-with-r-script-and-bash)
- [While, do, done flow control in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544229/while-do-done-flow-control-in-bash)
- [Bash does not remove leading whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064479/bash-does-not-remove-leading-whitespace)
- [bash: reading text from a string one character at a time, with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458743/bash-reading-text-from-a-string-one-character-at-a-time-with-whitespace)
- [Bash read file to an array based on two delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214431/bash-read-file-to-an-array-based-on-two-delimiters)
- [Using the internal field separator with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235373/using-the-internal-field-separator-with-curl)
- [C: IFS System() Vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873964/c-ifs-system-vulnerability)
- [How bash IFS is working in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933132/how-bash-ifs-is-working-in-this-example)
- [Use of the Internal Field Separator when capturing array data from a command in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453052/use-of-the-internal-field-separator-when-capturing-array-data-from-a-command-in)
- [How to use IFS with upstart script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575149/how-to-use-ifs-with-upstart-script)
- [Using a variable to pass grep pattern in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414324/using-a-variable-to-pass-grep-pattern-in-bash)
- [How is this bash script resulting in an infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991148/how-is-this-bash-script-resulting-in-an-infinite-loop)
- [When should we change the IFS variable back to its original value in scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182528/when-should-we-change-the-ifs-variable-back-to-its-original-value-in-scripts)
- [How to escape a variable in bash when passing to command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257388/how-to-escape-a-variable-in-bash-when-passing-to-command-line-argument)

This is the majority meaning, so I left it as is and wrote a tag wiki.

#### IBM [IFS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fifs%2Frzaaxkickoff.htm) (6)

- [Crystal reports not connectiing to Views from AS/400 IFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573974/crystal-reports-not-connectiing-to-views-from-as-400-ifs)
- [Punctuation in Java source changed to accented letters when copied to IFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561875/problem-in-ifs-stream-file-ccsid)
- [IFS file copy using JT400 in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205650/ifs-file-copy-using-jt400-in-code)
- [Calling write() C API from CL on iSeries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238294/calling-write-c-api-from-cl-on-iseries)
- [Copy stream file to printer file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049733/copy-stream-file-to-printer-file)
- [How do I programmatically determine the CCSID of a file in the IFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064817/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-the-ccsid-of-a-file-in-the-ifs)

Created [ibm-ifs](/questions/tagged/ibm-ifs) and retagged.

#### QNX [image filesystem file](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/ide_en/user_guide/builder.html#id26) (2)

- [How to generate ELF file for QNX IFS image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935290/how-to-generate-elf-file-for-qnx-ifs-image)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312322/how-can-we-force-linux-kernel-linking-from-qnx-build-file

Created [qnx-ifs](/questions/tagged/qnx-ifs) and retagged. I'm not sure if a specific tag is warranted. I haven't gone to look for other questions that might benefit from this tag.

#### [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_and_Financial_Systems) ERP (2)

- [Advice on choosing the best data warehousing tools for ERP system on Oracle 10g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410303/advice-on-choosing-the-best-data-warehousing-tools-for-erp-system-on-oracle-10g)
- [IFS Crystal Reports Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575276/ifs-crystal-reports-error)

Created [ifs-erp](/questions/tagged/ifs-erp) and retagged. I haven't gone to look for other questions that might benefit from this tag.

#### IFS [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) (1)

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920385/installing-ifs-lsp-sample-kills-internet

Created [winsock-lsp](/questions/tagged/winsock-lsp) and retagged. (Maybe [layered-service-provider](/questions/tagged/layered-service-provider) would be a better name, or should be a synonym.) The tag [lsp](/questions/tagged/lsp) needs to be disambiguated too; ideally it should be split into [liskov-substitution-principle](/questions/tagged/liskov-substitution-principle) and [winsock-lsp](/questions/tagged/winsock-lsp), but [liskov-substitution-principle](/questions/tagged/liskov-substitution-principle) is too long so I'm leaving those questions tagged [lsp](/questions/tagged/lsp). Out of 88 [lsp](/questions/tagged/lsp) questions, I've retagged 22 to [winsock-lsp](/questions/tagged/winsock-lsp) and 3 to other topics; I may have missed a few.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest option 2

- A new [ibm-ifs](/questions/tagged/ibm-ifs) tag, with a completed tag wiki
- A [completed tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/26793) for [ifs](/questions/tagged/ifs).

We can then retag the few questions that belong under [ibm-ifs](/questions/tagged/ibm-ifs). Hopefully mis-tagging won't occur in the future once the tag wikis are completed.